# If $x^{T}By = 1$, should $\operatorname{Tr}(Byx^{T}) = 1$?

Tags: matrices, vectors

would appreciate any hints with this question:

Assume $x$, $y$ are both $n \times 1$ vectors, and that $B$ is $n\times n$.

Given that $x^{T}By = 1$, should $\operatorname{Tr}(Byx^{T}) = 1$ ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true in general that

$$\operatorname{Tr}(AX)=\operatorname{Tr}(XA)\implies \operatorname{Tr}(x^T(By))=\operatorname{Tr}((By)x^T)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.